# Why i cannot generate pdf file with itext

Tags: java, swing, itext

So I tried to get data from my [database] table then generate a PDF from it. First, I tried to select the directory where I want to save the file with `JFileChooser`. Then, I tried to create the PDF inside the selected directories. Last, I tried to get all the data from my DB and insert it to my PDF.

The problem is that the PDF file is not generated and there is no error message showing.

```java
String path = "";
JFileChooser j = new JFileChooser();
j.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
int x = j.showSaveDialog(this);
if(x == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    path = j.getSelectedFile().getPath();
}
try{
    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(path + "abcd123.pdf"));
    doc.open();
    PdfPTable tbl = new PdfPTable(2);
    tbl.addCell("Class ID");
    tbl.addCell("Class Name");
    try{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM kelas";
        PreparedStatement st = (PreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            tbl.addCell(rs.getString("id"));
            tbl.addCell(rs.getString("nama"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    doc.add(tbl);
    doc.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

So I tried to change the path from

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(path + "abcd123.pdf"))
```

to

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\tes.pdf"));
```

And it works. But I want the path to be dynamic and not hard coded.

Comment: Which library you are using for the PDF? In many libs you have doc.save() (or similar method) to save the changes.

Comment: @Level_Up i used the itext library. I changed the question. because, The first question where i just tried to generate a paragraph inside the pdf already working. In this updated question. i tried to get data from my db and insert it to the pdf. Still figuring out why in not generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from your last edit of your question I will suggest to try

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(path + "\\abcd123.pdf"));
```

Also you can try to print the path to see what is the value of it.

By the way you should use file separator that works on Windows and Unix(Linux):

```
String fileSeparator = FileSystems.getDefault().getSeparator();
```

Comment: ohh yeahh i forget to put the backslash for the path